# How do I find duplicated values in related table and update them

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my situation.

**TABLE1:**

```
DOCUMENT_ID,
GUID
```

**TABLE2:**

```
DOCUMENT_ID,
FILE
```

The tables are joined by `DOCUMENT_ID`, meaning that `TABLE2` can have one or many rows with the same `DOCUMENT_ID`.

My problem is that `TABLE2` values for whole bunch of `DOCUMENT_ID` have same `FILE` values.

I need a SQL query that will get me all `GUID` and count how many rows in `TABLE2` for this `DOCUMENT_ID` have EXACTLY THE SAME `FILE` value (so that I can copy the `GUID` to Excel).

Then I need to UPDATE `TABLE2`'s `FILE` columns for these cases.

For instance if `DOCUMENT_ID` has three rows in `TABLE2` with same `FILE` value, I need to update two of them by adding a postfix like `FILEVALUE-1`, `FILEVALUE-2` and so on.

Hope I make sense.

To all experts thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get duplicates you might employ oldfashioned group by:

```
select table1.guid, table1.document_id, table2.[file], count(*) cnt
  from table1
 inner join table2
    on table1.document_id = table2.document_id
 group by table1.guid, table1.document_id, table2.[file]
having count (*) > 1
```

To directly update duplicates, you might use CTE:

```
; with t2 as (
    select id, 
           [file],
           row_number() over (partition by document_id, [file]
                              order by id) rn
      from table2
)
update t2
   set [file] = [file] + '-' + convert(varchar(10), rn - 1)
 where t2.rn > 1
```

Note that I've added ID as a placeholder for primary key. You need a way to identify a record to be updated.

[There is live test @ Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8da95/1).

Answer (score 0):

This will get you all FILES that have more than a Document_id

```
Select FILE, COUNT(DOCUMENT_ID) as DOCUMENT_ID from table2
group by FILE
Having count(DOCUMENT_ID)>1
```

Comment: You did not get me right. I need all GUIDs that have more than one identical value in the field FILE in related table2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTE to find out duplicate value from TABLE2:

```
WITH CTE_1 (DOCUMENT_ID,FILE, DuplicateCount)
AS
(
SELECT DOCUMENT_ID,FILE,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DOCUMENT_ID,FILE ORDER BY DOCUMENT_ID) AS DuplicateCount
FROM table2
)
select *
FROM CTE_1 
WHERE DuplicateCount >1
```

Comment: nice aproach, but its not working properly. Check this result: ---41592 038125 (2).TIF 2---
---41592 038125 (2).TIF 3---
---41592 038125.TIF 2--- 
---41592 038125.TIF 3---
---41592 038125.TIF 4--- ... results are "repeating" with different count.

Comment: FILE column is a type of varchar?

Answer (score 0):

I have 1 approach in mind, but not sure whether it is feasible at your end or not. But let me assure you, this is a very effective approach. You can create a table having an identity column and insert your entire data in that table. And from there on handling any duplicate data is a child's play.
There are two ways of adding an identity column to a table with existing data:

1. Create a new table with identity, copy data to this new table then drop the existing table followed by renaming the temp table.
2. Create a new column with identity & drop the existing column

For reference the I have found 2 articles : 
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/03/sql-server-add-or-remove-identity-property-on-column/
http://cavemansblog.wordpress.com/2009/04/02/sql-how-to-add-an-identity-column-to-a-table-with-data/